# Using htaccess to validate secure link query string - sub-folders affected

Tags: .htaccess

This is for a basic secure link.  I give users a link like:

```
mydomain.com/folder/index.htm?var=1234
```

Then in 'folder' I put an htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !val=1234
RewriteRule (.*) - [F]
```

It works - BUT, it's causing index.htm to fail to load items from sub-folders, like images from '`./folder/images`', or scripts from '`./folder/scripts`'.

Any ideas on how to fix this behaviour would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are flagging every url except `index.htm?var=1234` as forbidden

You can target only `index.htm` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+index\.htm.+$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !val=1234
RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
```

Comment: @Jim_1234 You are welcome. Don't forget to mark the question as solved